# How to prevent MVC from using a JSON property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an anonymously accessible action. This action using id and id2 to pass it along to the proper extension. id = extension name and id2 is the extension action. This is a generic system we have to create extensions and allow them to have anonymously accessible actions. This also means the request body can contain anything.

```
[Anoniem]
[NoCache]
public ActionResult Feedback(string id, string id2)
{
  return InternalPerformOrFeedback(id, id2, null, null);
}
```

An example of the complete postback URL would be:

```
Appname/Area/Controller/Action/Id/Id2
https://example.com/App/MW/Ext/Feedback/DigitaalOndertekenen/Feedback
```

If the URL is called without any JSON data MVC perfectly grabs id and id2 from the url and binds them to the parameters.

Now when the URL is called with JSON data MVC seems to bind the JSON property "Id" to the parameter id instead of grabbing it from the URL.

I have tried adding the [FromUri] annotation but that didn't give me proper results.

Any idea how to prevent MVC from using the request body to bind the parameters?

Comment: Wat do you mean _called with JSON data_? What is an example of the url that is not working and what is the result you are getting?

Comment: For example the request body contains a json string and the content type is application/json.  The result is that if the json string contains an "id" property. MVC suddenly uses that instead of the URL parameter.

Comment: You have shown a GET method. Setting the content type has no effect (a GET has no body). Again, if you want help, you need to shown the relevant code

Comment: The method accepts any type of method.

Answer (score 0):

You could clearly specify the route you expect with this attribute:

```
[HttpRoute("feedback/{id1}/{id2}")]
```

You could also specify that this method only accept Get request with:

```
[HttpGet]
```